# Cassandra daemon status is active(exited) after running for a while with no error

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm able to run cqlsh when Cassandra is running, but after about an hour (even with no interaction) it exits. No information in the system.log or debug.log regarding any errors, just information like this:

```
 INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-12-10 00:12:17,083 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 215ms.  CMS Old Gen: 64597120 -> 67315664; Par Eden Space: 51249152 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 4521424 -> 6356992
 INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-12-10 00:22:40,926 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 285ms.  CMS Old Gen: 67315664 -> 69958504; Par Eden Space: 51249152 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 6356992 -> 4498480
```

What else could I check?

Info:
Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64
Cassandra 3.11.1
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
488 MB Memory
4 GB Swap

Comment: First, you need to increase amount of available memory...

Comment: With that little memory you definitely need to disable swap, which you should do anyway.